# Linux application to download attachments to a dir?

Tags: php, linux

I need to automate a process whereby attachments are automatically downloaded from messages in a POP3 mailbox, and once complete, the messages get deleted. The attachments need to get output to some sort of folder which my PHP script can look at. I'm trying to avoid using PHP for download attachments, so I'm looking into using a linux program.

I've seen a program 'mpop' that could maybe do at least part of the job, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a programming question and answer site. Your question is not programming-related (it's a question related to finding software not related to programming), and therefore is off-topic here. I've voted to migrate it to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) where it's more appropriate. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) in order to become familiar with this site and what questions are (and are not) proper to ask here. We try very hard to keep things here on-topic so that SO remains a useful resource. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about Ruby and the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail)?

```
require 'mail'

save_dir = '/tmp/attachments/'

Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => '<username>',
                          :password   => '<password>',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end

Mail.all.each do |m|
  m.attachments.each do |a|
    begin
      File.open(save_dir + a.filename, "w+b", 0644) {|f| f.write a.body.decoded}
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Unable to save data for #{a.filename} because #{e.message}"
    end
  end
end
```